# Link dynamically created IBOutlet of UIPageControl to IBAction changePage

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, uipagecontrol, ios-universal-app

I have created UIPageControl dynamically and want to link it to the IBAction changePage function so can work on the scrollview content change while changing the page

I have used

```
[videoPageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

after I created the pagecontrol but while changing page its not executing changePage function I tried logging in changePAge function but its not executing the function

I am new to Ios development please de reply.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How do you initialise the videoPageControl?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the source, that I put together at:
https://github.com/CelusionGajendra/iOSSources.git

I have used a page control in viewDidLoad method. The Main view color is black and then when u swipe on page the page changes to load the red and green color views. The ChangePage method is being invoked.

Comment: Did the solution work for you? If so could you please update this as answer or up vote?